# Specify the return content type of a Controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger

I have the following as a `metrics.controller.ts` file:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiOperation, ApiResponse, ApiUseTags, ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { PrometheusService } from './prometheus.service';

@Controller('metrics')
@ApiUseTags('Misc')
export class MetricsController {
  constructor(private readonly prometheusService: PrometheusService) {}

  @Get('/')
  @ApiOperation({
    title: 'Prometheus metrics',
    description: 'Exposes default prometheus node metrics'
  })
  @ApiResponse({ status: 200, description: 'Prometheus metrics' })
  public getMetrics(): string {
    return this.prometheusService.getMetrics();
  }
}
```

However Swagger incorrectly indicates a **Response content type** of **application/json**, when the actual output is **text/plain**:

[image: Screen shot of output]

I have tried looking at the [Swagger docs regarding describing responses](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/), and the item I am looking for is the 'content' portion. However, that doc does not cover the TypeScript annotations. The [Swagger Core 2.X documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#operation) talks about an `@Operation` annotation, but I don't have a reference to that and I don't know where to get one--only `@ApiOperation` works.

The relevant version information from `npm ls` in the project directory is as follows:

```
+-- @nestjs/swagger@2.5.1
| +-- @nestjs/common@5.3.6 deduped
| +-- @nestjs/core@5.3.6 deduped
| +-- lodash@4.17.10
| +-- path-to-regexp@2.2.1 deduped
| `-- swagger-ui-express@3.0.10
```

What is the proper annotation to indicate a **Response content type** of **text/plain**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found out the solution is to `import ApiProduces from '@nestjs/swagger'` like so:

```
import { ApiOperation, ApiResponse, ApiUseTags, ApiProduces } from '@nestjs/swagger'

//...

    @ApiProduces('text/plain')
    public getMetrics(): string {
        //...
    }
```